# How to restore the panels after one of two monitors is unplugged (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, gnome

I have a monitor connected to my laptop, which I set to be the default one. After I unplug it, GNome doesn't recognize that and now I cannot see the panels, so I can't access anything. Is there are way to restore GNome back, like when you normally disable the second display?

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally unplugged your monitor, just reboot your laptop if it doesn't work follow the below steps

1. Boot your laptop in recovery mode
2. Drop to root shell prompt
3. Type the command `nvidia-xconfig`
4. Now type `exit` and resume to normal boot

if you don't want to reboot then plugin the monitor again and and type Fn+F7 for calling the external monitor and then got to System > Preferences > Monitors which it will open your graphic control (nvidia) and disable there

I used to follow the above steps when I has the same problem. :-)

-Viki